# Cefsharp MouseDown event [Part 2]

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I paraphrase my question. Since previous post failed.
I have a WinForms CefSharp browser application.
I need to use the hook to track down the mouse buttons and release them. Normal events in the form of this does not work.

I try this:

```
class ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor : NativeWindow
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

    const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            /*CefCustomObject._instanceMainForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                CefCustomObject._instanceBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("leftclick_down();");
            }));*/
        } else
        {
            /*CefCustomObject._instanceMainForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                CefCustomObject._instanceBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("leftclick_up();");
            }));*/
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with this code. And it lies in the fact that I need to track the HOLD mouse and the moment
unHOLD (sry for bad English). And here it works like CLICK.

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)`?

Comment: This condition for some reason does not work.

Comment: The way Chromium is structured makes it difficult, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L250 for a rough example to get you started, use Spy++ to get a better understanding of what's going on